# Best method to generate part numbers with ranging options

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, combinatorics

I have a part number that looks like this when complete: TCW-K1-A4-B21AA

The only constant is the TCW- portion, everything else specifies an option for the part number. My end goal is to be able to have all possible part numbers with every configuration in a csv file. My programming skills are limited so I made an attempt at solving my issue with javascript using the code below:

```
var tcwArray = [['TCW-'], 
['K', 'J', 'T', 'R', 'S', 'E'], 
['1-', '2-', '3-', '4-', '5-', '6-', '7-', '8-'], 
['A', 'B'], 
['1-', '2-', '3-', '4-', '5-', '6-', '7-', '8-', '9-'], 
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
['0', '1', '2', '3'], 
['0', '1', '2'], 
['1', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
['A', 'B']];

function allPossibleCases(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return [];
    }
    else if (arr.length === 1){
        return arr[0];
    }
    else {
        var result = [];
        var allCasesOfRest = allPossibleCases(arr.slice(1)); //recur with the rest of array
        for (var c in allCasesOfRest) {
            for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
                result.push(arr[0][i] + allCasesOfRest[c]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
var r=allPossibleCases(tcwArray);
```

This did not work for me, most likely due to memory limits. My question being is there a better language for me to do this in that I could learn quickly?

Comment: If it is a memory issue, why not just concatenate the individual results (instead of result.push) into a file and then read from the file (in chunks) instead of storing the whole thing in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to append to results only when number is complete (or store in file like Justin mentioned.)

```
var results = [];

function allPossibleCases(arr, number) {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return result.push(number);
    }
    else {
        var first = arr[0];
        var rest = arr.slice(1);
        for (var i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
            allPossibleCases(rest, number + first[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as *other* languages go, Python is relatively easy to get into.  Here is an implementation for this in Python:

```
all_descriptors = [
    ['TCW-'],
['K', 'J', 'T', 'R', 'S', 'E'],
['1-', '2-', '3-', '4-', '5-', '6-', '7-', '8-'],
['A', 'B'],
['1-', '2-', '3-', '4-', '5-', '6-', '7-', '8-', '9-'],
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
['0', '1', '2', '3'],
['0', '1', '2'],
['1', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
['A', 'B']
]
all_part_numbers = []

# Recursive part number generator, all possible permutations for given list of descriptor lists
#   descriptors - the list of lists of descriptors
#   part_number - the part number string which has descriptors added to it with each recursion
def generate_permutations(descriptors, part_number):
    if len(descriptors) == 1:  # this is the farthest right descriptor
        for char_descriptor in descriptors[0]:
            # finish up, add last character descriptor to part number
            all_part_numbers.append(part_number + char_descriptor)
    else:
        for char_descriptor in descriptors[0]:
            # call this function recursively with the descriptor fields to the right of current field
            #     and append current descriptor to end of part_number
            generate_permutations(descriptors[1:], part_number + char_descriptor)

generate_permutations(all_descriptors, "")

outfile = open("part_numbers.csv", 'w')
for part_number in all_part_numbers[0:-1]:
    print("{},".format(part_number), file=outfile, end="")
# separate printing of last element so there is no comma at the end
print("{}".format(all_part_numbers[-1]), file=outfile, end="")
```

To save on memory, you could skip appending the part-numbers to all_part_numbers and print straight to file instead.  But, you'd have to figure out a way to avoid that trailing comma on the last part-number.  Maybe that doesn't matter, though.